# Convert GMT date formate to Simple date in PHP

Tags: php, date, laravel

I want to convert my date from GMT to simple Date format , i look around on many questions and answers on this site but not succeed.

I have Date

> $date = '2010-12-01T02:00:00:000-0500';

and I want to convert this date to `12-01-2010` , i already tried with the `date('d-m-Y',strtotime($date));` but it not work here.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: hi use carbon package laravel already using this package to handle date http://carbon.nesbot.com/ check this tutorial for more reference https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/11

Comment: @umefarooq I want o use this in View is there any way for laravel5? I already check with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27181009/use-carbon-on-views-laravel

Comment: if its is coming from database check laracast tutorial link already there you can create carbon object in model and later you can use it in view

Comment: its not for the database , it's from the api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to create a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object out of your formatted date, like this:

```
$date = "2010-12-01T02:00:00:000-0500";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d\TH:i:s:uP", $date);
echo $date->format("m-d-Y");
```

output:

```
12-01-2010
```

Comment: @HardyMathew So is this question answered? As long as you didn't accepted any answer it still remains as unanswered on the Stack

Comment: I got the answered but i am looking for the laravel , However i will accepted yours.