# use carbon function in laravel view(Blade template)

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I get some values from the database and I passed those values into view from the **controller**. now I want to use that data with some `carbon function` in **Laravel view**.

In my View file I wrote

```
foreach($customer as $time){

        $create= $time->created_at;
        $update= $time->updated_at;

        $create_at_difference=\Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime($create))->diff(\Carbon\Carbon::now())->days;


}
```

when I try like this it returns `"Class 'Carbon' not found"`

**How can I do this?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use carbon on Views laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27181009/use-carbon-on-views-laravel)

Answer (score 39):

It works with global namespace to my view.blade.php as

```
      {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($row->posted_at)->diffForHumans() }}
```

Comment: yes it is all with the global namespace as none was declared in the blade, therefore you will have to make sure you start with `\Carbon\Carbon::`

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use the namespaced class, you don't need the first slash:

```
 $create_at_difference=Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime($create))->diff(\Carbon\Carbon::now())->days;
```

You should just write Carbon\Carbon instead of \Carbon\Carbon.

That is a quick solution. But, using classes directly in your views is a bad idea. You can add more functionality to your model by creating a function that will return current created at difference.

lets say you have Customer model, you can go that way:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Customer extends Eloquent
{
      public function created_at_difference()
      {
           return Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime($this->created_at))->diff(Carbon::now())->days;
      } 
}
```

then in the view you can access this like:

```
@foreach($customers as $customer)
   {{$customer->created_at_difference()}}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option, i think it's better put this line of code on top of your class:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers


use Carbon\Carbon;


class MyController {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use blade injections for the cleanest result.
Example:

```
@inject('carbon', 'Carbon\Carbon')
...
<span>{{ $carbon::parse($model->created_at) }}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue and this is what worked for me

```
$create = $time->created_at;

$create_at_difference = Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime($create))
                    ->diff(\Carbon\Carbon::now())->days;
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not repeat `\Carbon\Carbon`, just try

`\Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime($create))->diff(\Carbon::now())->days`

Comment: doesn't work FatalErrorException in 6a56f855267d18143d461317c820047f line 76:
Class 'Carbon' not found

Comment: do i have to import carbon in my view file

Comment: I just tried like this, its working fine {!! \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()!!}

Comment: do i need to import carbon to my view file like this  <?php use carbon/carbon;?>

Comment: no, no need to import carbon, just try to remove your code, and paste my code, see what you get ?