# How use carbon in Laravel 5.2 application-wide

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

How to use Carbon in Laravel 5.2 without `use Carbon\Carbon;` added in every View and Controller..?

Comment: No it's not added to every View or Controller. If you need to use Carbon functions you need to include with use!

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/easier-datetime-in-laravel-and-php-with-carbon

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add the following line to the aliases array in the config/app.php:

```
'Carbon' => 'Carbon\Carbon'
```

And you need to add `use Carbon;` every class where you want to use it.

Comment: Infact i can alias it just fine and call it afterwards like \Carbon, but the autocomplete goes to hell :)

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/easier-datetime-in-laravel-and-php-with-carbon

Answer (score 2):

You can declare some fields in your models using the following structure:

```
protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'disabled_at','mydate'];
```

All of those fields will automatically be Carbon instances and you will be able to use them in your views like:

```
{{ $article->mydate->diffForHumans() }}
```

This is the answer I provided some time ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27181009/use-carbon-on-views-laravel/33317965#33317965).

And [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) is the documentation from Laravel for that

Comment: In order to use ->diffForHumans() function doesn't he have to include "use Carbon/Carbon"?

Comment: not if he declares the `protected $dates` properties in his models :)

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for the tip @El_Metalla

Comment: The tips are great yeah, and thanks to the laravel team :)

Comment: Yep, thanks to the Laravel team, I'm just copy pasting here haha

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/easier-datetime-in-laravel-and-php-with-carbon

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have on my helpers.php

```
function myCarbon($date)
{
  return $date != '' ? \Carbon\Carbon::parse($date) : '-';
}
```

Then on any controllers and views:

```
myCarbon($model->field)->format('F d, Y');
```

And since I usually have `mm/dd/yyyy` and `mm/dd/yyyy H:i` on my blades, I have these on my helper file:

```
function mydateFormat($date)
{
  return $date != '' ? myCarbon($date)->format('m/d/Y') : '-';
}

function mytimeFormat($date)
{
  return $date != '' ? myCarbon($date)->format('H:i') : '-';
}

function mydateTime($date)
{
  return $date != '' ? myCarbon($date)->format('m/d/Y H:i') : '-';
}
```

Now you can use this application-wide on any controllers and views.

*(note: function names are sample only, not what actually I am using, change based on your need)*