# Carbon.php The separation symbol could not be found Data missing

Tags: php, laravel, date, laravel-5, php-carbon

First, I retrieve all the records,

```
//get inventory items
$inv = inventory::all();
```

and then I loop on the retrieved records and modify the created_at and updated_at data to make it more human readable date.

```
foreach($inv as $i){
    $i->created_at = date("M d, Y",strtotime($i->created_at));
    $i->updated_at = date("M d, Y",strtotime($i->updated_at));
}
```

but it returns me this error,

> InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 425: Unexpected data
>   found. Unexpected data found. The separation symbol could not be found
>   Data missing

any ideas, help, clues, suggestions, recommendations please?

here's my model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class inventory extends Model
{
    protected $table = "inventory";
    protected $primaryKey = "item_id";
    public $incrementing = false;

    public function profile(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\profile','username');
    }
    public function inventory_images(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\inventory_images','item_id');
    }
}
```

and in blade, I can just use

```
{{ date("M d, Y",strtotime($i->created_at)) }}

{{ date("M d, Y",strtotime($i->updated_at)) }}
```

and it work just fine.

Comment: Did you happen to do something fancy with your `inventory` model to make it handle date properties with Carbon?

Comment: @mopo922: no I haven't sir

Comment: Is there more code that you're not showing, where you use Carbon for something?

Comment: @mopo922: I didn't use any carbon or such, in the blade template, it render just fine but when I try to do it in my controller, it gives me that error.

Comment: Looks like it may happen automatically: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27181009/use-carbon-on-views-laravel#answer-33317965 Can you plz share the code in your view where you print these dates?

Comment: it has something to do with your date format, what date format are you using in your model? From the error, it seems that in your model you have a date format which differs from the one you pass in

Comment: @mopo922: please see my updated post.

Comment: @SteD: please my updated post

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you're going about this the wrong way. The data in your database doesn't need to be *more human readable*, only the display that a human actually `interacts` with.

To solve this, we will create a custom `accessor` method that will apply to all calls for the `created_at`. You can recreate this for the `updated_at`.

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($timestamp) {
    return Carbon\Carbon::parse($timestamp)->format('M d, Y');
}
```

Then when you call `$model->created_at` your attribute will return in that format.

If for some reason you absolutely need the date stored in that format, then you need to add an attribute to your model telling it that the `timestamp` columns should be formatted according to a specific type, such as:

```
protected $dateFormat = 'M d, Y';
```

**Sidenote**
The reason that *Carbon* is involved is that it is applied to all of the columns generated by `$table->timestamps()`, so the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns.
Furthemore, if you add more columns in the model to the `protected $dates = []` array, those will also automagically be handled by *Carbon*.

Comment: I have added "public function getCreatedAtAttribute($timestamp) {
     return $timestamp->format('M d, Y');
 }" but it returns me an error "Call to a member function format() on a non-object" and pointing on the line 20 which is the "return $timestamp->format('M d, Y');" any ideas?

Comment: @CodeDemon That's true, Do `return Carbon::parse($timestamp)->format('M d, Y')`

Comment: I have no carbon installed in my laravel 5.2 app and I don't want to install that extension yet at this moment, any alternative way without involving carbon?

Comment: @CodeDemon It's prebundled `with` Laravel. You can't avoid it `use Carbon\Carbon`. You can also just simply format the string as you'd like using your method if for some reason you want to avoid using `Carbon`, which is baked in.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, where should I add the accessor method and that too for one particular column of the table.?

Answer (score 2):

**So simple error please do  like this**

check your date format (d-m-Y)  then use the same format

```
$shipDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i',Carbon::parse($request->date)->format('d-m-Y') . " " . $request->time);
```