# Using protected $dateFormat throws trailing error

Tags: laravel, date, date-format, octobercms, php-carbon

I am trying to format the date at the model using:

```php
protected $dateFormat = "Y-m-d";
```

and I am getting this error:

```
"The separation symbol could not be found Trailing data" on line 582 of C:\wamp64\www\israplanet.com\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Carbon.php
```

Using

```php
protected $dateFormat = "Y";
```

causes this error:

```
"Trailing data" on line 582 of C:\wamp64\www\israplanet.com\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Carbon.php
```

This example is from the [October docs](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/mutators#date-mutators).

Whats is wrong here?

Comment: Read about mutators: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators

Comment: I did. and took this code from there. nope (

Comment: I don't believe this is an OctoberCMS problem, I think it's Laravel's Carbon: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37958512/451969 So, it's likely you're trying to specify a date format for a column with data already in it, out of format (which is what "Trailing data" I think is telling you), or you're formatting in an unexpected way. If you want to know for sure, search the source for `Trailing data` and see how/where that comes from.

Comment: again, i took this format from laravel/october docs. 
and getting this error.
tried trailing data also. only thing I can think of is clean database. I do have some records already in another format. but still, it should only take the date and format it, not change.

Comment: I did read the same docs. i think there's unexpected behavior you're not understanding, which is encapsulated in this sentence: _This property **determines how date attributes are stored in the database**, as well as their format when the model is serialized to an array or JSON:_ So you're monkeying with the actual data, from what I can tell. And it's complaining it doesn't understand what it sees in those columns, based on the format you're specifying.

Comment: i cleared the table and tried to make new record. getting an error now that format is invalid.
i'm for sure not understanding something since i cannot fix this thing.

Comment: I just tested this and the result is the same. It works fine when you create an object and use it immediately since it contains the carbon instance, but when you fetch existing data from the table the issue occurs. This happens at `Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2017-05-24 00:00:00')`, where the first param is the format specified and the second is the value from db.

Comment: the thing is in october it's auto.
i should interfere to catch the data and then use it.
problem that i'm using not only one record, but big collection with relations

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the example you have given (ie: using `protected $dateFormat = "Y-m-d";`) but when I do something like this I tend to use an accessor on the model:

```
public function getFormattedDateAttribute($value)
{
     return $this->created_at->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Obviously `created_at` would need to be replaced with the name of the date field. You'd then be able to access it in Twig as `{{ array.formatted_date }}`.

Comment: https://octobercms.com/docs/database/mutators#date-mutators
in docs. 
checking your solution.
but i'm sure it must work, only need to figure out how )

Comment: not working.
i'm using this to get collection with dateformat. using handlebars, and date filter not working.

Comment: @aleXela - Why aren't you formatting the date with Twig, as it's intended to be used? `{{ variable_name|date("Y-m-d") }}`? Having a template variable called `array` and a property of `formatted_date` is a bit abstract, too.

Comment: problem that i'm using handlebars. and no such filter there. giving an error.

Comment: Aargh, handlebars. You're supposed to [do that with Javascript](https://formatjs.io/handlebars/). Like: `{{formatDate your_date_property "Ymd"}}`, with `Ymd` being a custom date formatter. If you're going to use Handlebars, that's the way it expects to be done, with the full datetime being given as the source.

Comment: ill try to use helper.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot name this as good answer, but for now i at least can continue.
I simply changed format of the columns (created_at and updated_at) to date format and it stores the way i wanted it, but i always trying to fix problems (this habbit takes a lot of my time).

another option is to use handlebar helper for this. 
But i want to understand the problem in the root.

(btw - thanks for answers)

Comment: So the solution to the original problem was to change the column type from something to a `Date` type? Is that using the same exact code in your question? What was the field type before?

Comment: sorry, didnt get it straight
it was timestamp.