# Laravel Excel import returning wrong date

Tags: php, laravel

I have an Excel file, where I have a date column. The date looks like "17.07.2020".

I'm using Laravel and Maatwebsite Excel import. When I'm saving the imported data to MySQL, the date in MySQL is always "1970-01-01".

Here is the code, which I have now:

```
return new Product([
    .......
    'discountBeginning'  => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['discount_beginning'])
]);
```

I would like to format the date from Excel to "2020-07-17".

Comment: I made an answer, but read your question again. How is ```discountBeginning``` being stored in your database?

Comment: To be able to answer this definitely, you need to provide the output of `$row['discount_beginning']`? Looks like the `strtotime()` call is the bug here, since it is just returning the Unix Epoch Time (1970-01-01). Perhaps `$row['discount_beginning']`contains a format that `strtotime()` is unable to parse?

Comment: The output in the database is always "1970-01-01", even though the date in Excel is 17.07.2020

Comment: I also got that `1970-01-01` date. What really worked for me is `$your_date = PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($row['your_date']);` from the [comment section of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68733581/1883256). In the excel row, I got a string as `2022-05-29` (for example) and that worked!

Answer (score 3):

**Try this**

```
$date = new DateTime($row['discount_beginning']);
echo $date->format('d.m.Y');
```

Comment: I dont think this will work given the format in OPs excel file. ie) 6.5.2020 is it May 6th, or June 5th?

Comment: I am wrong DateTime has the same interpretation, d.m.Y.

Comment: Okay i think my updated answer is work for @Jakub Kříž

Comment: I get this error: `Failed to parse time string (44710) at position 4 (0)`

Answer (score 0):

You are using Laravel, so you already have access to the awesome Carbon library. For how data is formatted in your excel file (day.month.year), you can use it like:

```
return new Product([
    .......
    'discountBeginning'  => \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', $row['discount_beginning']),
]);
```

Once you have the carbon instance, you can format it however you would like according to [php's date syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) like:

```
$date = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', $row['discount_beginning']);
$date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: I've tried your code, but it's returning an error "The separation symbol could not be found"

Comment: I'm using Excel's default date format, which is exactly "17.07.2020"

Comment: It won't even let me dd somehow. Always the same error "The separation symbol could not be found".

Comment: Well, it looks like its grabbing the date in General format, where 17.07.2020 looks like 44029 in Excel, even though column format is date.

Comment: Yes, the output in log was 44029. It's one of the formats in Excel, like for example Time, Currency, Date, Percentage etc. https://bettersolutions.com/excel/formatting/number-tab-general-format.htm

Comment: esbot\\carbon\\src\\Carbon\\Traits\\Creator.php(662): Carbon\\Carbon::rawCreateFromFormat('d.m.Y', 44029, NULL), that number is the $row['discount_beginning'], which in Excel looks like "17.07.2020"

Comment: Ok, I'll add that info. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$date =  "17.07.2020";
$d2 = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', $date)->format('Y-m-d');
dd($d2); // returns: "2020-07-17"
```

you can also try to append `->toDateString();` if your returned date is not a string. If it is already a string, this will fail.

Comment: What if I get the `The separation symbol could not be found Data missing`  error?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37957595/carbon-php-the-separation-symbol-could-not-be-found-data-missing