# All date columns are equal to 1970-01-01 using laravel / maatwebsite Excel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to import data from excel file to database using Laravel.

So I'm trying the following code :

```
public function model(array $row)
    {
              $datee = $row["date_naissance"];

              $time = strtotime($datee);

              $date = date('Y-m-d',$time);
    
              $age = Carbon::parse($date)->diff(Carbon::now())->y;

              if($row['artiste'] == 'oui'){

                 $value  = 1;

            }else{

                 $value = 0; 
            }

            $casting = new Casting();
            
            $representant = new Representant();


                $representant->nom_prenom   =  $row["nom_prenom"];
                $representant->cine   =  $row["cine_representant"];
                $representant->lien_casting       = $row["lien"];
                $representant->save();
            
                $casting->nom = $row['nom'];
                $casting->cine = $row['cine'];
                $casting->date_naissance = $date;
                $casting->lieu_naissance = $row['lieu_naissance'];
                $casting->mineur = 1;
                $casting->id_representant = $representant->id;
                
                $casting->id_type_facturation = Type_Facturation::where('type_facturation',"like", "%".$row['type_facturation']."%")->value("id_type_facturation")  ;
                 $casting->artiste = $value;
                $casting->fonction = $row['fonction'];
                $casting->id_type_casting = Type_Casting::where('type_casting',"like", "%".$row['type_casting']."%")->value("id_type_casting") ;
                $casting->tel1 = $row['tel1'];
                $casting->tel2 = $row['tel2'];
                $casting->email = $row['email'];
                $casting->qualification = $row['qualification'];
                $casting->adresse = $row['adresse'];
                $casting->ville = $row['ville'];
                $casting->pays = $row['pays'];
                $casting->id_filiale = Auth::user()->id_filiale;
                $casting->save();
               
        }
```

I'm using the following controller :

```
    public function importFile(){

          try {

              Excel::import(new ProjectsImport,request()->file('fichier'));
   }
   catch (\Maatwebsite\Excel\Validators\ValidationException $e) {

      $errors = $e->failures();
       foreach ($errors as $failure) {
         $failure->row(); // row that went wrong
         $failure->attribute(); // either heading key (if using heading row concern) or column index
         $failure->errors(); // Actual error messages from Laravel validator
         $failure->values();

     return response()->json(['errors' => $failure->errors()]); // The values of the row that has failed.
     }

   }

          return response()->json(['success' => 'Data is successfully added']);
    }
```

Everything works fine but when I check my database I find that all dates in the `date_naissance` column are equal to `1970-01-0` .

And When I did that :

```
$casting->date_naissance = PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($date);
```

I get the following error :

```
message: "Class 'App\\Imports\\PhpOffice\\PhpSpreadsheet\\Shared\\Date' not found"
```

If you have any idea please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need a slash before `PhpOffice`, like `\PhpOffice\...`. Or you can import that `Date` class (aliased to prevent issues with `date()` function), like: `use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date as ExcelDate;` at the top of your file, then `$casting->date_naissance = ExcelDate::excelToDateTimeObject(...)`

Comment: @TimLewis thank you for your reply , I tried that but I get now the following error :`message: "A non well formed numeric value encountered"`

Comment: So that fixed your first issue, what line specifically is that new error pointing to?

Comment: in this line ` $casting->date_naissance = ExcelDate::excelToDateTimeObject($date);`

Comment: Ah ok, so same line. Can you `dd($date)` and update your question with the new error and output? `$date` might be `null` or something else.

Comment: I get `"1970-01-01"`

Comment: Yeah, `$date` should be an integer, like how `\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject(44418)` returns `date: 2021-08-10 00:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00),`. Since you're pre-casting `$row["date_naissance"]` to a date, you're breaking it. Just do `$casting->date_naissance = ExcelDate::excelToDateTimeObject($row["date_naissance"]);` and it _should_ work.

Comment: Awesome! Glad that's working :) Welcome to the wonderful world of Excel Date Formats; they're weird, but as long as you know that Excel's dates are all integers, and aren't really compatible with `date()` helpers and whatnot, then you'll be fine. Cheers!